# How to remove this specific white line in a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing

If you look at the image below taken from the oracle java tutorial, there's a thin white line just under where the tip of the cursor is, just above the blue shading of the tab background. How do I get rid of that specific white line? I've managed to customize everything, and it's frustrating that I can't get rid of that white line/change its appearance!

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It may be recommended by default you must highlight it by a red line to better exlain your answer

Comment: I don't have any image-editing software on this computer, is it not clear from the image? I thought it's pretty clear by the explanation "there's a thin white line just under where the tip of the cursor is"

Comment: Thats the sepetation of the tab1 from the rest actually the seperation between panel to other panels useless to remove but you can try some color combination to just minimize the only difference

Comment: Specifically, which property is it in the UI manager? I've tried all of them

Comment: The only thing you can do is to just set the background colors of panels plus the jframe container by the why you want this to do so please explain a little more that can help you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ButtonTabComponent class that comes with the demo.

What you see is the border of the button being painted. If you don't like it then comment out the MouseListener that is used by the button:

```
//addMouseListener(buttonMouseListener);
```

Comment: This seems odd. Why would adding a listener change the UI?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe, look at the source code. The listener enables/disables the painting of the border on mouseEntered/exited.